# What does 9+ Notifications on YouTube mean?

Tags: youtube, notifications

Please tell me what 9+ notifications mean. Since they removed the number tab, I want to know how many unread notifications are there. What does 9+ notifications mean?

Answer (score 1):

“9+” means a number greater than 9.

It could mean 10, but it could just as easily mean 27 or 42 or 153 or any other number. It just means “more than nine”.